# Change part of column names by numbers

Tags: python, pandas, list

How can I replace part of a column name of a pandas data frame by elements in a list.

For example these are my column names:
`['area_Smith, 'area_Jones', 'area_Johnson', average_volume_Smith, ...]`

Now I would like to give numbers to all names: so I would make list called names with `['Smith', 'Jones', 'Johnson', ....]` in it and another list called number with `['0', '1', '2', ....]` in it.
Then I would like replace Smith with 0, Jones with 1 etc.
So the result should be:
`['area_0, 'area_1', 'area_2', average_volume_0, ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

cnt = defaultdict(lambda c=count(1): next(c))

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(
    r"(.*_)(.*?)$", lambda g: f"{g[1]}{cnt[g[2]]:0>4}", regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   area_0001  area_0002  area_0003  average_volume_0001
0          0          1          2                    3
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
   area_Smith  area_Jones  area_Johnson  average_volume_Smith
0           0           1             2                     3
```

Comment: How can I change every number to have four digits, like for example: Smith should be 0001, Jones 0002, Johnson 0003 etc.?